# Word or phrase for difference between expected and reality

Tags: english-to-german

Is there a word in German I can use to describe the difference between the expected result and reality?

My boss is German and he constantly thinks our database has more information on a per person basis than it actually contains and it would be great to explain this in a term or terms he would better understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first word jumping to my mind here is

> Diskrepanz

But this most probably will not solve your problem, as it only describes a difference between two results.

The best way IMHO is to describe the actual given result, in this case:

> Die Datenbank enthält zu jedem Nutzer nur Nutzernamen und E-Mail-Adresse.
>   The database only contains username and e-mail address for each user.

If you want to stress the difference between the boss' expectation, you can prepend:

> Im Gegensatz zu ihren Erwartungen …
>   As opposed to your expectations …

I would consider this as a bit rude though.

Answer (score 1):

> Unterschied zwischen Erwartungen und Realität

Comment: Please try to add some explanation. Your suggestion is useful, but not helpful. Currently OP probably does not know how to handle this phrase.